# How to pass complete response of one feature as a request to another feature

Tags: karate

payload.json

```
  {
 "channelData": {
"data": "CHANNEL_DATA",
"salesChannel": "WEB",
"createdBy": "WEBSITE",
"accountId": "#(accountId)",
"sessionId": "#(accountname)"
 }
}
```

Request.feature

```
@ignore
Feature:

 Scenario:

  * def Request = read('../payload.json')
  * def headersData = { "Content-Type" : "application/json"}
   Given url BaseUrl + '/account/'+'#(accountId)'
   And request Request
   And headers headersData
   When method post
   Then status 200
```

account.feature

```
 @ignore
 Feature:

Scenario:
  * print temp
  * def headersData = { "Content-Type" : "application/json"}
   Given url BaseUrl + '/accountdata/'
   And request temp
   And headers headersData
   When method post
   Then status 200
```

Account-token.feature

```
  Feature: 
  Scenario: identify the reference account

 * def reqRes = karate.call('../Request.feature')
 * def temp =  karate.pretty(reqRes)
 * def account = karate.call('../requests/account.feature',{temp : temp })
```

I want to pass response of  Request.feature as a request payload of account.feature. When I try above case, value for temp is printed in an array. [#response of Request.feature] how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please study this example carefully, it will answer all the questions you have and you will see where you are going wrong: [`call-feature.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/callfeature/call-feature.feature)

For example, to get the `response` out of a `call` result, you have to "unpack" it:

```
Scenario: create kittens
    * def result = call read('create-two-cats.feature')
    * def temp = result.response
```

Comment: I unpacked the response out of call:                                                                        
     * def reqRes = karate.call('../Request.feature')
     * def temp =  reqRes.response                                                                       
     * print temp  // result for this steåp is null //                                                                     
     * def temp1=karate.pretty(reqRes.response)                                                                 
     * print temp1 // result for this is (..????..) // Please advise.

Comment: @MurugeshSubramaniam here is my advice: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I could able to achieve the result by using  * def temp = $reqRes[0].response.